# How to implement Enable/Disable button on foreach record?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this JavaScript to Enable/Disable Update button.
I need when stats id checked to EnableUpdate button. With this script functioning but at first row, at other rows not in function.
How to Implement foreach row-records?

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#status').click(function () {
        var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
        $('#btnApprove').prop('disabled', $('#status:checked').length == 0);
    });
});
```

HTML Code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MessageID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)
        </td>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmptyMessage)
        </th>
        <td>

            @Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")


        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBox("status")
        </td>

        <td>
                 <input type="submit" name="Update" id="btnApprove" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("UpdMessages", "Home", new { MessageID = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MessageID)})'" />
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is View:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the html code please?

Comment: @Gilles Heinesch Question Updated

Comment: I can't see the html item with the "status" id?

Comment: IDs are singular

Answer (score 0):

You cant use id to track it as id are unique can be once in the dom . you have to use dynamic class for both status checkbox and button show that whenever a status gets check fetch the dynamic class of both or just pass parameter to change function and then make it disable. try use data- attribute to add dynamic class if you dont want any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to find button in same row and update it's prop.

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('#btnApprove').prop('disabled', this.checked);
```

Comment: This is good, just i need property when is checked, then to enable, when is uncheked then Disable.

Comment: didn't get you what do you mean by "need a property when is checked"?

Comment: Yes, but by default button is disabled, now i need when click check status, then enable button

Comment: How to do reverse ?

Comment: you mean on uncheck it's not enabling back?

Comment: At this moment if i Check button go to disabled, if Uncheck go to enable, i need reverse, when icheck Enable, when uncheck Disable

Comment: then try this,  $(this).closest("tr").find('#btnApprove').prop('disabled', !this.checked);

Comment: I already tried, but not functioning this. Another solution ?

Comment: better you provide rendered template structure, that would be easy for us to provide solution

Comment: I solved, changing this code: .attr("disabled", !$(".status:checked").length); Thank you.